# "export '_DisposeViewRepeaterStrategy' was not found in '@angular/cdk/collections'

Tags: angular, angular-material, node-modules

Facing the below error in the Angular application.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/material/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/table.js 58:58-86
"export '_DisposeViewRepeaterStrategy' was not found in '@angular/cdk/collections'
```

Tried:

- Running `npm install --save @angular/cdk`
- deleting the node_modules and reinstalled.

But it doesn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had this problem today aswell, for me the problem was a mismatch between @angular/cdk and @angular/material.

```json
"@angular/cdk": "~10.1.3",
"@angular/material": "^10.1.3" <-- this becomes 10.2.0
```

Comment: Should it be same version?

Comment: From what I noticed it should. Make sure you have the same character in front of the version (~, ^) to avoid mismatching. For the difference between them see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json

Comment: worked for me as well